# How to redirect a wrong search on my wordpress website to the error 404 page?

Tags: redirect, 404-error

For example, my wordpress website is `www.example.com`. If I type `example.com/abcdef` or any other url that does not exist, it redirects to my **custom 404 page** without any issues.

However, when I search something, the url changes `to www.example.com/?s=abcdef` and it shows wordpress's default 'Nothing Found' page. Is there a way I can redirect a wrong search's to my **custom 404 page** or can I change wordpress 'Nothing found' page?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to disable example.com/?s=* completely having that query string hit your custom 404?

Comment: Thanks for replying. I don't want to disable 'example.com/?s=*' completely if it screws up the website's search function. I am looking to change the page that shows up when the search doesn't get any results. If I can customize it and add some of my custom text and image to it that would be better. If not, can it redirect to the error 404 page? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A search shows the search template regardless of whether or not there are any results, which is either `search.php` or `index.php` if that template doesn't exist.

If you want to load an entirely different template, you can use the `search_template` filter. Assuming your theme's 404 template is `404.php`:

```
function wpd_search_template( $template ) {
    if( ! have_posts() ) {
        $template = locate_template( array( '404.php' ) );
    }
    return $template;
}
add_filter( 'search_template', 'wpd_search_template' );
```